# Synchronous vs. Asynchronous HTTP requests

Tags: ios, http, asynchronous, synchronous

I am in the process of converting a JavaScript-based hybrid app to a native iOS app. When I started developing the app with JavaScript, I was disappointed to find out that if you want to make an HTTP request, you have to do it asynchronously. I tried to get around this in various ways, basically:

```
var done = false;
$.post(url, data, function() { done = true; });
while (!done) {}
//Continue
```

But I came to find that this is ugly and just plain bad practice, so I got over it and just did it asynchronously.

So when I started with iOS I was excited with the idea that I might be able to do it synchronously, but again I was disappointed to find that the recommended practices are asynchronous, favoring closures or delegates to handle responses.

My question has two parts:

1. Why is it such common practice in almost every case for HTTP requests to be made asynchronously instead of synchronously?
2. Is there a way to make synchronous requests in iOS that isn't ugly or problematic?

Essentially, I've always wanted to be able to do something like:

```
var response = SubmitHTTPPostRequest(url, data)
```

Is this not really a thing? I never learned this kind of thing in school, so I apologize if this is a rudimentary question. I've just never understood why this is the way it's typically done.

Comment: The problem with synchronous requests is that they freeze the UI.

Comment: Blocks make asynchronous code quite elegant.

Comment: Do you think using a block is uglier than freezing your UI?

Comment: I accidentally deleted a line in my post, and just fixed it. I wasn't saying that async code is ugly, I was saying that my plan to get around async using a waiting mechanism was ugly. And yea, the whole "freezing my UI" thing was enough to convince me that async is the best way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand the process from sending a request to getting a response. The request will most likely go through some network adapter, to some server, back to the adapter and then back to your CPU. In general there are no cases where there is only one processor involved, in the case I described are 3 but usually there are more. That means synchronisation as doing all the work in one process is impossible since multiple processors are involved. The path to synchronisation (as already mentioned) is for your current thread to wait. I can not agree that will freeze your UI but will freeze your thread (which will freeze the UI if it is the main thread). Still putting the whole process into another thread which will wait for response will produce many other issues and questions such as "should I create a thread for each request", "memory consumption if responses take too long to return?"...

I can understand you want this synchronisation so you can do the operation in a single method but in the end this is exactly what makes an ugly code. Your method then consists of creating the request, getting response, processing response and processing the data received all in one. This might seem a good idea on the beginning but when this method becomes too long you will want to refractor the code into at least 3 methods which by coincidence is exactly what you need to do with asynchronous request. So to answer your second question: Very unlikely, the asynchronous procedure looks much less ugly.

What you should do and is done in most cases is to create some class that handles your requests and responses so from the UI part of your code you only need to do a single call. Lets say you have a table view on which you will display a list of your friend received from some social network. When you first come to this list you would like some activity indicator view to notify the user the data is loading, then send some asynchronous request to get the friends not caring when and if the response will return but when the response is received you simply remove the activity indicator and reload the table view with new data received. Now I hope you can imagine this is a very elegant code and by doing so you enable the user to be able to cancel the request by pressing back.

So the main reason for doing request asynchronous is not to block the threads because that may generate multiple issues or even blocking the main thread which will block the UI and if the main thread is blocked for too long the application will be killed in iOS (watchdog). And the reasons to do synchronisation? Well, in long term I can not think of any, you should always break operations into many methods and use callbacks.

Comment: Yea, this makes a lot of sense to me now. It would make sense if the request was guaranteed to be almost instantaneous, but it obviously never is. If you were to do a smart synchronous method and put a thread to sleep instead of busy waiting, you would still need another thread to receive the response and wake up the original thread, which would defeat the purpose of doing it synchronously to begin with.

Comment: Just one more thing about using asynchronous requests: Remember to do the callbacks on the main thread unless you explicitly want to continue the execution on a separate thread. It is easiest to use:
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //do the UI callback
            });

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should be very clear with synchronous and asynchronous terms.

When Synchronous request sent, caller has to wait for the request to complete the process.
And Asynchronous request don't wait for finish.

**As per stack overflow answer , i have read once :**

When an HttpHandler is called, a thread pool thread is used to run that request and the same thread is used to process the entire request. If that request calls out to a database or another web service or anything else that can take time, the thread pool thread waits. This means thread pool threads spend time waiting on things when they could be used to process other requests.

In contrast, when an HttpAsyncHandler, a mechanism exists to allow the request to register a callback and return the thread pool thread to the pool before the request is fully processed. The thread pool thread starts doing some processing for the request.At that point, the thread pool thread that was processing the HTTP request is returned to the pool to process another HTTP request.

**Your Answers :**

1.Because , asynchronous request do not wait for task to complete. send request and while in the same time thread can perform other task without waiting. i use ASIHttpRequest in my ios app.

2.We can send request synchronously but not common this days in practice.